# using identity 2.0 and make single connection string

Tags: asp.net-identity, identity

i am using identity 2.0 in my project using db first approach .
in my web.config file i have two connection string

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-VATmvc-20170119121340.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-VATmvc-20170119121340;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="VatEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.VATModels.csdl|res://*/Models.VATModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.VATModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=Vat;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and my identity model class contains

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

if i replace default connection with vatentities then it is giving error ...
actually i want to make a single connection to db so that i can use anywhere in the project .my db contains identity tables.

Comment: So your connection string is not correct... or the DB behind "VatEntities" does not have all the required tables. And what is the error?

Comment: i want to make these two connection strings into a single one so that i have to use only one db class to access my databas e..